# If I have a washing machine with feet not attached at all to the floor, will it begin to walk on a opposite angular velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

The title is self-explanatory, but I will give some more details.
So, let's suppose the washing machine can move, that is, it doesn't have any protections for not moving. Let's also suppose it's standing on a floor that favors movement (less friction than usual, let's say). So, when it starts centrifuging, will the whole machine start to "spin" on an opposite direction than the centrifuge? And if so (or not), would someone care explaining?

Comment: Is the inside of the washing machine rotating around the vertical axis?

Comment: It is. It rotates around the vertical axis.

Comment: Re, "will the whole machine start to 'spin'...?" If "whole machine" means all parts of the machine _except_ the tub, then yes, if the coefficient of static friction between the machine's feet and the floor is sufficiently low, then the _frame_ of the machine will "spin" in the opposite direction to the tub. (Won't "spin" very far before it is stopped by its hoses, or its electrical cord, or by crashing into walls, the clothes dryer, etc. If it was possible for the washer to break its hoses and its electrical cord, then it would stop spinning because... No  more electric power.)

Comment: But why opposite? Is it because of Newton's 3rd Law?